# If you're evacuated on a flight paid for by your government (eg civil unrest, volcanic ash delays), are you ever entitled to the frequent flyer miles?

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, emergencies, event-based-effects

This came about after a Facebook discussion over this article:

[Abbott government cracks down on bizarre requests for help from Australian travellers](http://www.theage.com.au/federal-politics/political-news/abbott-government-cracks-down-on-bizarre-requests-for-help-from-australian-travellers-20141203-11z4z8.html):

Question 15:

> 15) Some travellers evacuated from civil unrest in Egypt on government
>   funded flights questioned why they were not entitled to frequent flyer
>   points. Similarly, some travellers evacuated from the 2004 Boxing Day
>   tsunami made seat requests, including for first class

While it's arguably cheeky asking for first class, given that when a company pays for their employees, the employees can usually get FF points, are airlines exempt from providing points in situations like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what Australia does, but in similar situations the US pays in advance for the evacuation - by whatever means - and bills the person being evacuated.

Comment: Gotta love a downvote with no comment.  Care to elaborate on the reason?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The phrasing "government funded flight" suggests that the flight was chartered by the Australian government. Charter flights are not usually eligible for miles.  For example, Rule 9.3.1 of [Qantas's Frequent Flyer rules](https://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/program/terms#jump8) says:

> Subject to the exclusions in clauses 9.3.2 and 9.4, Points for air travel may be earned only for paid travel or Any Seat Awards [...] on regular scheduled flights [...]

and Rule 9.4.1(c) specifically says:

> 9.4.1 Points are not earned for travel on [...] (c) charter flights;

The case might be different if your government buys people tickets on a regular scheduled flight, rather than chartering the whole plane.  But evacuations like this are usually undertaken when scheduled flights are not operating.

Comment: +1.  The government is not going to buy your seats on a regular scheduled flight, and costs for charters are billed straight back to the passengers.

Comment: It's also almost certainly variable depending on local law.  My guess would be that even if the German govt bought a citizen a ticket on a commercial flight, trying to claim FF miles would run afoul of the same laws that classify doing so for business travel as stealing from your employer.

Comment: This is an [article](https://au.news.yahoo.com/thewest/latest/a/8749102/free-flight-out-of-cairo-for-aussies/) providing some details on a 2011 flight charted by the Australian government to evacuate their citizens from Cairo.  On this occasion no cost recovery was planned.

Comment: Conversely this [article](http://this.org/blog/2011/02/09/egypt-evacuation/) states that the Canadian, US and UK governments planned to recover costs from citizens assisted in fleeing the same unrest.